# Where are css injector files stored on the server?

Tags: theming

I'm using this module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector

In the backent, the files show up at this path:

```
public://css_injector/css_injector_20.css
```

But in FTP I look in public.html and I can't find theme

They are not in here either:

```
/home/vincoixt/public_html/xuzo.com/sites/all/modules/css_injector
```

So where are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Injector stores it's files in the files directory under:

```
'public://css_injector/css_injector_' . $crid . '.css';
```

as defined in [`_css_injector_rule_uri`](http://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites!all!modules!css_injector!css_injector.module/function/_css_injector_rule_uri/7.43)

This often maps to the following folder:

*sites/default/files/css_injector*

See also: [`css_injector_init`](http://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites!all!modules!css_injector!css_injector.module/function/css_injector_init/7.43) for how the files are added by that module.

Comment: Yes indeed, they are here: sites/default/files/css_injector ;)